# How does one yank a function call in vim?

Tags: vim, editing

Suppose a line of text reads:

```
$x = ( frobnicate( foo( bar( $x, $y )[ 1 ]))[ 1 ]);
```

The cursor is on the 'f' of 'frobnicate' and I want to yank the text which includes the call to frobnicate.  (That is, everything up to the 3rd closing parenthesis.  I can certainly do:

```
y3f)
```

or do it interactively with

```
vf);;y
```

but neither of these is appealing.  (I don't want to have to count the '3' manually, nor do the repeated find until I hit the end point.)  Is there an easy way to accomplish the move from 'f' to the matching closing paren?  I'm thinking something like the v_i 'inner word' motion command.

Comment: I made a plugin based on tpope's vim-surround that includes text objects for function calls: but more generally [vim-surround-funk](https://github.com/Matt-A-Bennett/vim-surround-funk) also allows you to delete, change and yank a surrounding function call, and paste it around any text object (and since there's a text object for function calls, so you can paste it around them too!)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`y%` seems to work.

From `help %`:

> Find the next item in this line after
>   or under the cursor and jump to its
>   match. inclusive motion. Items can
>   be: `([{}])` parenthesis or
>   (curly/square) brackets

Comment: I finally understand why % looks to the right for a brace to match!   I've always been annoyed with % and wanted it to move to the left to find the brace to match, snice I often have the cursor inside a pair of braces and want to move to the end, but this is clearly better behavior.

Comment: @William Pursell: You could use `[{` or `[(` to move to the left (and up) to find an opening brace or parenthesis.

Comment: @William Pursell: in this case you might want to have a look at yi( or ya(, which mean respectively "yank inside parenthesis" and "yank a parenthesis". Of course, any command like va{, di[, ca( is also valid... :help object-select

Answer (score 0):

You could try `yel%` to position the cursor to the opening parentheses and then jump to the closing one with `%`, but it does not look much more efficient than your current solution.

The only advantage is that you don't have to count anything, and it works with nested call.

Edit :
as pointed by Peter, `y%` works and is a superior solution (even if I don't quite understand why it works. Vim is amazing!)

Comment: It took me a while to understand it to. I just tried it. The help OTOH is quite clear as to why it works. The cursor first moves right to any of `([{}])` and after that to the other half of the pair.